Git rebase is failing to delete my commit
I want to delete a specific commit from my repository.

The yellow one in this case
So I entered the following command

and this file opened up

the red one here is 2.9.1 fa7c710 is 2.9.2 and 15e9b64 is 2.9.0
then I proceeded to delete the yellow line and saved and closed the file

then this message popped up in terminal

however as you can see in this picture all it seems to have done is shift my HEAD to 2.9.1 while the yellow commit is still there

What am I doing wrong? I just want the yellow commit to be deleted.
I have also tried the many other things like changing the # Rebase line, changing pick to drop instead of deleting it, changing the number after HEAD~ etc but to no avail. How do I get rid of that commit?

Rebasing doesn't delete commits. What you want is to get rid of it from your branch's history. And it looks like it succeeded. The display you see might have mislead you, the unwanted commit shows here only because it's part of upstream/master's history.

Yellow one was merged into master, plus extra merge commit was added. If you do git reset --hard @~, effectively removing merge commit, all commits, that were introduced by that merge commit (single yellow one), will be deleted too. Try to reproduce that behavior in different branch first, just to make sure.

First make sure that your HEAD is a tip of the branch.

Yep, that works as expected. Just try.

It’s easier if you use git log output as code blocks instead of images.

If your goal is linear history, you should rebase branches to be merged onto destination branch, then ff merge.

You rebased your detached head. Git even said so. The commits you made aren't connected to a branch. Fix this by checking out a branch and then running your rebase -i.
Frankly, if you have to ask how to fix this, then you're not meant to trifle with such power. It's too easy to screw things up.
My advice is, unless it's hurting something other than your sense of aesthetics, I'd leave that commit well enough alone.
Also, I can see from your digraph, upstream/master is the remote branch. Rebase only modifies your local branches. The remote branches aren't affected unless you force-push.
In your case, unless you also delete that tag (v2.9.2) absolutely everywhere, that commit will always exist in your repository. Once defined, tags have a way of coming back if you're not extra-careful.
Gaining Better Insight into Git
git status is your friend and can tell you much about what's going on in your repository.
If you can't be arsed to type git status every time, you can add repo state indicators into your prompt using git-prompt.sh:
# Add these lines to ~/.bashrc:
. /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '

You should adjust the git-sh-prompt line to where it resides on your system. I just included the path that's the default in Ubuntu 23.04.
